# RxJava changing thread after concat map

Tags: java, android, multithreading, transactions, rx-java

Hello RxJava masters,

In my current Android project, I encountered some deadlock issues while playing with RxJava and SQLite. My problem is :

1. I start a transaction on a thread
2. call a web service and save some stuff in the database
3. concat map another observable function
4. try to write other stuff on the database ---> get a deadlock

Here is my code :

```
//define a scheduler for managing transaction in the same thread
private Scheduler mScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());


Observable.just(null)
            /* Go to known thread to open db transaction */
            .observeOn(mScheduler)
            .doOnNext(o -> myStore.startTransaction())
            /* Do some treatments that change thread */
            .someWebServiceCallWithRetrofit()
            /* Return to known thread to save items in db */
            .observeOn(mScheduler)
            .flatMap(items -> saveItems(items))
            .subscribe();

public Observable<Node> saveItems(List<Item> items) {
    Observable.from(items)
            .doOnNext(item -> myStore.saveItem(item)) //write into the database OK
            .concatMap(tab -> saveSubItems(item));
}

public Observable<Node> saveSubItems(Item item) {
    return Observable.from(item.getSubItems())
            .doOnNext(subItem -> myStore.saveSubItems(subItem)) //DEADLOCK thread is different
}
```

Why all of sudden RxJava is changing thread? Even if I specified I want him to observe on my own scheduler. I made a dirty fix by adding another observeOn before saveSubItem, but this is probably not the right solution.

I know that when you call a web service with retrofit, the response is forwarded to a new thread (that's why I created my own scheduler to get back in the thread I started my sql transaction). But, I really don't understand how RxJava is managing the threads.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The side effect operators (as does `flatMap`) execute synchronously on whatever thread calls it. Try something like

```
Observable.just(null)            
          .doOnNext(o -> myStore.startTransaction())
          .subscribeOn(mScheduler)      // Go to known thread to open db transaction 
            /* Do some treatments that change thread */
          .someWebServiceCallWithRetrofit()                      
          .flatMap(items -> saveItems(items))
          .subscribeOn(mScheduler) // Return to known thread to save items in db
          .observeOn(mScheduler) // Irrelevant since we don't observe anything
          .subscribe();
```

Answer (score -1):

As of my knowledge `doOnNext` method is called in different Thread, than the code before it, because it is running asynchroniously from the rest of the sequence.

Example: You can do multiple rest calls, save it to database and inside `doOnNext(...)` inform a view/presenter/controller of a progres. You could do this before saving to database or/and after saving to database.
What I would suggest you is "flatMapping" a code.

So the `saveItems` method would look like this (if `myStore.saveSubItems` returns a result):

```
public Observable<Node> saveSubItems(Item item) {
return Observable.from(item.getSubItems())
        .flatMap(subItem -> myStore.saveSubItems(subItem))
}
```

Using "flatMapping" guarantees that the operation is run on the same thread as the previous sequence and the sequence continues then `flaMap` function ends.